# What is the proper way fill a void in drywall finish along a shower?

Tags: drywall, painting, patching-drywall, drywall-mud

I found that the masking tape was embedded in the mud between skim coat and original texture when I removed it. What is the best way to fix this?  Can I use caulking on the smaller parts and skim the really bad section and prime/paint again?

UPDATE - I reskimmed the wall with the pan and it turned out well. The areas around the door moulding with gorges were filled with 3m patch plus primer. All areas were primed and then used GE max shield caulking on the edges with the moulding as well as the pan edge, frog tape made it a very clean line.  Pained a touch up on the new spots then a final layer to avoid flashing. It turned out very good and the drywaller got their bad review.

[image: Worst Case, mud exposure about 5 mm at the widest]

[image: What most of this column looks like]

[image: Typical break]

[image: Other trim area]

Comment: Contract disputes are off topic here. I've revised your post to focus on the problem alone. Feel free to revise further, but keep in mind that back story and blame aren't relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Sand, skim coat drywall mud, rinse and repeat until flat.    Should just take two coats.

It would help if you can take off the trim.    It would be much faster and the problem you will have is the mud buildup right on the edge of the trim.   If you can't take it off you can use a utility knife to help remove (this small line will get caulked anyway).

Also you need to wait like 3-4 days to sand unless you use quickdry.    I know it is a really thin coat and you might want to sand it at 1-2 days but the area that is built up at the trim - if you sand it when it is a tiny tiny bit wet it will come off in chunks and you start over.

And also again when you are skimcoating you start at the trim and feather out on your first coat.   Second coat you go straight up and down press harder on trim side and then with a clean knife (6") going to the other side and pressing hard down to the outside (where there is no mud).    This will leave a tiny hump in the middle - 2 inches from trim - and will be sanded flat.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I am thinking it will be the answer for the strip (shown in the first 3 pictures) but am hoping to just caulk or use patch primer plus for the other trims where its not as bad as the first 3 pictures.

Comment: It's your house, @ChucktheDuck, fix it any way you want. But if you're going to ignore the advice given, why did you bother asking?

Comment: @FreeMan is right in his answer - this should be the contractor doing this but not sure what was in contract.    Mud never goes over painters tape unless you are doing a craft project.   This isn't a hard fix and will take you longer to mix the mud than to skim coat and sand.     There really isn't a different way to do it.

Comment: This is the right answer. Be sure to clear away dust between applications, as the void is likely to be filled with dust, preventing adhesion of subsequent layers.

Comment: That thin patch will not take days to dry unless R.H. is absurdly high. In fact, with a fan it'll be ready in 20 minutes using standard mud or topping compound. As soon as it's no longer dark it's totally dry.

Comment: @isherwood - talking about the stuff that gets stuck under trim and it takes days.   I have done this scenario a ton.   You don't have a to wait on the second coat as long.    Giving advice to a non-pro.     If he has 20 min set drywall mud sure he can sand 2 hours later.   Not sure why people that are comfortable enough using 20 min set would ask this question on a DIY site.

Comment: Dmoore, is the advice to sand/skim for the first 3 pictures and not the 4th (its at a wall with moulding only and not the moulding/tile trim strip in the first 3 pictures?  I think that would be hidden with caulk but want to prefill so the caulk won't have as much mass to cycle and crack.  I agree with what you said for the strip (first 3) except the issue is the height of the existing flat surface is higher than the tile moulding, and didn't want to skim it higher again.

Answer (score 1):

The "best way" to fix it is to call the contractor and tell him you're withholding the final payment until he comes and does touch up on it.

What's that, you already paid in full? Let him know that he'll be getting bad reviews until he comes back.

Comment: that is what happened and being ignored, at least I have pictures of his work and the work contract with his header on it.

Comment: I'd give him a "final warning", @ChucktheDuck, that you'll be posting bad reviews on every review site you can find as well as sharing on all social media sites you can get hold of. Give him a last chance to make it right. Of course, if he still refuses, you're still up for repairing it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a joint between drywall and a shower pan. I think this joint should be caulked with an acrylic, paintable caulk. Drywall tape is prone to bubbling here. The wall and pan will move at very different rates with humidity and temperature, as bathrooms are the most extreme rooms in the house.

Comment: It would be difficult to caulk a void that wide and have it look good. Caulk shrinks, so it won't remain flat. No tape is needed anyway.

Comment: Corect its at the edge of the vertical of the shower, so it will get caulked either way.  i think shrinking the void may have to be done, by trying to level with some of the primer/spackle in 1 to get it level, then do the caulking, maybe with clear silicon to deal with the differently expanding surfaces in thermocycling, but only if I get the redone layer nice, or it will be paintable acrylic.